# UICollectionViewCell size and rotation

Tags: uiview, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

In my `UICollectionView` I have a cell that should take the entire width of the device. Here is how I set the size for the item:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 120);
}
```

I have found that on rotation, the width of the cell does not change. I can resolve this using `[collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]` in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` but this isn't satisfactory. What if the user rotates while in another screen in my app? I will need to add the same to `viewWillAppear`. What about if the rotation occurs while the app is backgrounded? Now I need to add it for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification.

What confuses me most is that this is *not* required for my custom headers in the same collection view. The following supplementary views correctly re-size on orientation change:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 40);
}
```

Where am I going wrong? What should I do to have the cells re-size automatically to fill the width of the collection view?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late I know but could you solve this by subclassing flow layout and adding?

```
 - (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds {
  return TRUE;
}
```